# How do I get started with Virtual PC on Windows 7 Pro?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I would like to set up a Virtual PC VM on my Windows 7 Pro host machine. On the Microsoft VPC page I chose to download only VPC, not the damned XP Mode poster child, and I got to download the file *Windows6.1-KB958559-x86-RefreshPkg.msu*.

After installing that and restarting, I have a Virtual PC start menu item, but all that does in open an Explorer window to my *C:\Users\Brady\Virtual Machines* folder. Where is the management GUI where I can create a new VPC etc?

Comment: A better desktop virtualization solution would be VMWare Player or Oracle VirtualBox.

Answer (score 5):

There is a custom menu option for the folder for "Create virtual machine". The right click menu for an existing virtual machine will have a "Settings" menu item. Opening a virtual machine runs it.

The XP Mode is worthwhile to grab as it's a basically a free copy of XP Pro and has desktop integration.

[image]